# Loading Specific version of Bootstrap on Particular Web Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

we have two versions of Bootstrap loaded one at the beginning at the login page and another one to the main page as they are completely isolated after loading

Here is a scenario, when the main page is loaded in multiple tabs one after other and after Signing out from one session causing that particular tab to redirect to the login page 
But when rest of the tabs kept open, a modal popup screen gets triggered telling you that you had been signed off and clicking continue button lands directly into the login page

In that particular instance, two versions of bootstrap get loaded into the single page making the modal to fade after three seconds and breaking the rest of the structure where the classes had been included

As I'm looking for a solution in jQuery or JavaScript to call the necessary bootstrap plugin (i.e., by removing and adding) to load in particular page of the website.

For instance, loading the specific Bootstrap plugin on the login page as well as in the main page by removing and adding

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="..."> snippets.`

Whether is it possible to achieve the above scenario or by any other method could it be approached to solve.

Comment: Your time would be much better spent by fixing your whole site to use a single version of Bootstrap. Any workaround would be a hack which results in more wasted time should you need to make any future changes

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Possibly, Is there any jQuery script to accomplish the above scenario?

Comment: Nothing out of the box, no

Comment: i wouldn't recommend doing this, but if i had to i would do it in server code, not js

Comment: Sounds New. Could you brief in detail taking some code @mjw

Comment: what are you using to serve your pages? php, asp.net, etc? add your bootstrap references dynamically at load time from the pages that need specific versions.